# Teamcity + Ionic - build for iOS & Android

Tags: ionic-framework, continuous-integration, teamcity

I would like to use Teamcity to CI & generate build & artefacts for iOS & Android from Ionic app. I thought that I will able to do it on the Linux virtual agent but I think that there will be a problem with building for iOS.

I am a newbie in using Teamcity so I would like to ask what is best practice to make CI & build for iOS/ Android using TeamCity.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build the iOS ipa you will need a mac computer.  If you do not want to install your Teamcity server on the Mac you will need to have a mac "[agent](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-agent.html)" that your build process will use to build the ipa.  You will also need a Mac (and Apple Developer Account) in order to upload your ipa.

The Android apk can be built anywhere as long as Android Studio is setup on the machine properly.

As a best practice, keep in mind that if you have two computers, one can build the apk and one can build the ipa.  This will speed up your build processes as these two steps can be time consuming.  Building in parallel will significantly reduce this time.

There are several 3rd party tools that have been developed to integrate with various CI/CD platforms like Teamcity.  [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) and [App Center](https://appcenter.ms) (formally Hockey App) are just two of the many available tools that can help you automate parts of your build.